# Can't create vulkan device only in debug

Tags: c++, graphics, c++17, vulkan

I'm making a vulkan renderer and when I try to create a logical device it throws the following exception on vkCreateDevice only in debug mode:

Exception thrown at 0x00007FFBA327A34B (vulkan-1.dll) in Game.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.

Here's the code (By the way this was made mostly following the vulkan-tutorial.com tutorial):

```
bool FindQueueFamilies(VkPhysicalDevice device, uint32_t* indices)
    {
        bool found = false;

        uint32_t queueFamilyCount = 0;
        vkGetPhysicalDeviceQueueFamilyProperties(device, &queueFamilyCount, nullptr);

        VkQueueFamilyProperties queueFamilies[512];
        vkGetPhysicalDeviceQueueFamilyProperties(device, &queueFamilyCount, queueFamilies);

        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < queueFamilyCount; i++)
        {
            const auto& queueFamily = queueFamilies[i];

            if (queueFamily.queueFlags & VK_QUEUE_GRAPHICS_BIT)
            {
                if (indices != nullptr)
                {
                    *indices = i;
                }

                found = true;
            }
        }

        if (!found)
        {
            Loggers::Error("Didn't find queue family!");
        }

        return found;
    }

...

void* RenderDevice::CreateVulkan(void* physicalDevice)
    {
        //Logical device
        uint32_t indices = 0;
        FindQueueFamilies(*((VkPhysicalDevice*)physicalDevice), &indices);

        float queuePriority = 1.0f;
        VkDeviceQueueCreateInfo queueCreateInfo{};
        queueCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DEVICE_QUEUE_CREATE_INFO;
        queueCreateInfo.pNext = nullptr;
        queueCreateInfo.flags = 0;
        queueCreateInfo.queueFamilyIndex = indices;
        queueCreateInfo.queueCount = 1;
        queueCreateInfo.pQueuePriorities = &queuePriority;

        VkPhysicalDeviceFeatures deviceFeatures{};

        VkDeviceCreateInfo createInfo{};
        createInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DEVICE_CREATE_INFO;
        createInfo.pNext = nullptr;
        createInfo.flags = 0;
        createInfo.queueCreateInfoCount = 1;
        createInfo.pQueueCreateInfos = &queueCreateInfo;

        createInfo.enabledExtensionCount = deviceExtensionsCount;
        createInfo.ppEnabledExtensionNames = deviceExtensions;

        createInfo.pEnabledFeatures = &deviceFeatures;

        VkDevice device;
        if (vkCreateDevice(*((VkPhysicalDevice*)physicalDevice), &createInfo, nullptr, &device) != VK_SUCCESS)
        {
            Loggers::Error("failed to create logical device!");
        }

        VkQueue graphicsQueue;
        vkGetDeviceQueue(device, indices, 0, &graphicsQueue);

        return &device;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like you meant `physicalDevice` instead of `*((VkPhysicalDevice*)physicalDevice)`, since that's what vulkan-turorial.com uses and that's also what I use in my rendered. Was that your problem? Also keep in mind that access violations can be caused by bad pointers.